# How to add or remove item from RibbonGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I have a Ribbon, in which I have some kind of tabs. On one tab I have two RibbonGroups. What I want to achieve is when I click RibbonMenuButton located in RibbonGroup (first), I want to add some item (eg other RibbonMenuButton) to the RibbonGroup no 2. How can I achieve this with C#?

```
<Custom:Ribbon Name="RibbonMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="RibbonLoaded" Grid.Row="0">
        <Custom:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <Custom:RibbonApplicationMenu KeyTip="F">
            </Custom:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Custom:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <Custom:RibbonTab Header="Home" KeyTip="H" >
            <Custom:RibbonGroup x:Name="ClipboardGroup" Header="Home">
            </Custom:RibbonGroup>
            <Custom:RibbonGroup x:Name="ConnectionGroup" Header="Connect">          
            </Custom:RibbonGroup>
        </Custom:RibbonTab>
        <Custom:RibbonTab Header="Script">
            <Custom:RibbonGroup x:Name="ScriptsGroup" Header="Scripts">
            </Custom:RibbonGroup>
        </Custom:RibbonTab>
        <Custom:RibbonTab Header="Charts">
            <Custom:RibbonGroup x:Name="chartsGroup" Header="Charts">
                <Custom:RibbonMenuButton Label="First Chart" Name="firstChart" LargeImageSource="Resources/chartIco.png" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="firstChart_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                <Custom:RibbonMenuButton Label="Second Chart" Name="secondChart" LargeImageSource="Resources/chartIco.png" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="secondChart_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            </Custom:RibbonGroup>
            <Custom:RibbonGroup x:Name="chartsTools" Header="Tools">
            </Custom:RibbonGroup>
        </Custom:RibbonTab>
</Custom:Ribbon>
```

This is sample of my code. What I want to achive is when I click RibbonMenuItem fron "chartsGroup" RibbonGroup, I want to add items (checkboxex, textboxes etx.) to the chartsTools RibbonGroup.

Comment: FYI if you want to get serious with WPF and Ribbons you might want to take a look at [Fluent](http://fluentribbon.github.io/) as it has way more features and is easier to work with from my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but now I dont want to rewrite all application. Do you know how can I achive this with standard Ribbon?

Comment: uhm in that case we do need at least some code. For instance we would need to know if you can access the groups in C# (do you've a reference to them?) or if you'd need to crawl through the Ribbon and find the relevant groups.

Comment: I have edit my question.

Comment: are those items 'fixed'?`Meaning are the controls that should be displayed always the same?

Comment: Yes. This is core which I need to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the controls that are to be displayed are always the same, the easiest approach would be to just add them in XAML and set their `Visibility` to `Collapsed`.

Then you either use `RibbonMenuButton.MouseLeftButtonUp` or `RibbonMenuButton.MouseLeftButtonDown` EventHandler or use the `Command` pattern (if you're using MVVM or something alike).

Inside the Command/EventHandler you then set the `Visibility` of the controls that are relevant to the selected `RibbonMenuButton`to `Visible` and the `Visibility` of the irrelevant controls to `Collapsed`.

In MVVM you'd have to bind the `Visibility` of the affected controls to something on your `ViewModel`, maybe a boolean (in that case you need a `boolean`/`Visibility` converter), and set those bools from your `Command`.

If you'd be using a `ToggleButton` instead of those `RibbonMenuButton`s you could also directly bind the `Visibility` of the controls to the `Toggled` state of the responsibile `ToggleButton`, of course you'd need a converter again. Or bind to the `Enabled` state, if you'd rather have them greyed out.

===================================

For a more modular approach, you've two possibilities:

1. Go with the above method, but add `if` statements when changing the `Visibility` to `Visible`. I'm not sure how you'd determine which functionalities to enable, but that should handle all possible situations as long as all features are always inside the main program and you just don't want to always show all functions.
2. Use dependency injection (easiest to set up is probably MEF). Put 'extra' methods and their WPF controls in seperate MEF modules. You also need at least one interface, best to put it in a third assembly that is then referenced by the modules and your main program. On startup use `ImportMany` to load all modules, then go through that list with a `foreach` loop and get the WPF controls from those modules. I think you'd need two or three methods that are defined in the interface for that:

   - one method to get the actual Ribbon control that needs to be added to a `RibbonGroup`
   - one method that returns something to determine where that control goes (in which group/which position), this may need to be split into two methods, if you want to specify a group and a position inside that group
   - optional: A method that allows you to set the current object for that module. So if the user selects an object on which he/she wants to work, you need to let every module know which object that is. Either you let your main program set that object on every module when the object is being changed OR you create a second interface that is implemented by your main program and use an `Import` on your modules for that interface. Inside the module's eventhandler/command you can then query the main program for the current object.

Comment: What if not? I understand this approach, but Im not sure if in the future I need to add some other icons.

Comment: well you could always just add those controls/icons as well and just extend it. But if you're after something more modular, something like 'on system A I want functionality X, Y and Z but on sysmte B I only want functionality X and Z', you'd need a somewhat different approach. Please leave a comment if that's what you're after and I'll extend the answer.

Comment: Yes, this is something I looking for.

Comment: extended my answer, hope that covers what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for all ideas :)

Comment: @Tatarinho you're welcome ;) thank you for marking my answer!